# Incorrect rendering of Noto Sans Telugu font when using java.awt.Graphics drawString()

Tags: java, image, fonts, graphics, rendering

I am using Java's `java.awt.Graphics drawString()` method to render some text on an image. The font that I am using is [Noto Sans Telugu](https://fonts.google.com/noto/specimen/Noto+Sans+Telugu) and java version is 1.8.0_291. But the rendering of the text on the image is incorrect. Text is getting rendered using code similar to below code:

```
        String key = "గ్గిం";
        BufferedImage bufferedImage = new BufferedImage(170, 30, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
        Graphics graphics = bufferedImage.getGraphics();
        graphics.setColor(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
        graphics.fillRect(0, 0, 200, 50);
        graphics.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        graphics.setFont(Font.createFont(Font.TRUETYPE_FONT, new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream("/Users/abhishek.bansal/Downloads/Noto_Sans_Telugu/static/NotoSansTelugu/NotoSansTelugu-Regular.ttf"))).deriveFont(20f));
        graphics.drawString(key, 10, 25);
        ImageIO.write(bufferedImage, "jpg", new File("/Users/abhishek.bansal/Downloads/image.jpg"));
        System.out.println("Image Created");
```

The text should be rendered as in the first line of the code block, but instead gets rendered like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dXwqN.png). Is this a problem with the font or a bug in the Java's graphics library? Or is it probably a bug in the implementation above?

Comment: I can reproduce this problem in Java 8, but it appears to be fixed in Java 9.